# Cannot start MongoDB Server 'react-scripts' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, nodemon, react-scripts

I am creating a MERN Stack App and when I run `nodemon server`, i get this error
`C:\Users\utkarsh\chaiDB\mern-chaicoffeebiscuit>nodemon server
[nodemon] 2.0.2
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter`rs
`[nodemon] watching dir(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting`react-scripts start server
`'react-scripts' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...`

It worked succesfully until i started to work on the frontend using reactJS.
Now I have the full app completed. but the mongoDB server does not run now.
I have already tried commands like `npm install react-scripts --save` but still, i see the same error. I even reinstalled my Windows 8.1 (i loved the project by my  heart and wanted to complete it)

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar error but after a few minutes I realized the terminal wasn't in the correct folder. Try rechecking that you're in the correct folder that you made to handle the back-end.